# how to pass token to browser url in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i've an app whcih sends email to users to reset their passwords

this is the link i send to the user email to be able to do password reset

```
http://localhost:8081/reset/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MmU2YWJmMmMzMzI0Mjk1NGQyNmVjZjIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTk0ODkzODEsImV4cCI6MTY1OTQ5MDI4MX0.6omB-TkXXcwrjv0MaJQxltyERIoJZmkm8sY74AAqgxo
```

but each time i try to access the link i get

```
Cannot GET /reset/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

this is my route

```
 { name: "reset", path: "/reset/:token", component: Reset },
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    password: "",
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log("the id is :" + this.$route.params.token);
  },
  methods: {
    async handleSubmit() {
      const response = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/reset-password", {
          newPassword: this.password,
          token: this.$route.params.token
        })

        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
   
  }
};
</script>
```

please how can i go about these

Comment: it may cause by the dot character `.` in your URL, regularly it should URL encode to `%2E`

Comment: @yueyongdong how can i go about it and testing with the . in post man always give a valid request

Comment: cause you visit it you get `Cannot GET /reset/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9`, obviously it is not a complete URL

Comment: @yueyongdong  i just shortened the url ,i'm tryting to get /reset/:token

Comment: First, the reset password should work as a backend API, not as a Vue route, the way you write is like to pass through vue component. About the fault, I think it can not view the `Reset` component, so it give the error `Cannot GET /reset/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9`, cause your code is not complete, so i can not see where your code's mistake

Comment: There is a build URL encoder for JS. Use `encodeURIComponent(token)` while feeding the token to the router params. And for decoding use `decodeURIComponent`

Comment: @KiranParajuli please how can i go about this

Comment: Where is this big link sitting? In the user mail?

Comment: @KiranParajuli send the link to the user email then if the user clicks the link, it takes them to the front end route http://localhost:8081/reset/:token

Comment: hmm, then you should encode the token|URL while building that link for the mail content (backend side IMO)

Comment: @KiranParajuli is there not a way i can display the link without decoding, if you can help me answer the questiion

Comment: There is no need to encode dots in URL - it is a completely valid symbol. The problem comes from the Webpack-dev-server. You should inspect the output in your terminal to see if there is any clue about what is happening. The problem is not in VueRouter.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, I agree with you. Keeping this in mind, @xander I want to ask what is logged from that `console.log` in the mounted hook. Please see the whole `this.$route.params` in case of breaks. Also is there a complete token in the browser URL?

Comment: @KiranParajuli the page didn't load so i'm not getting any response and no token in the browser